# jquery filter search should select matching DIV´s according to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery filter search to search through list of DIV's that are generated by loop that is fetching data from database. So every chunk of info has the same Div wrapped around it self.

My Problem is that the search is searching through the whole texts and excluding everything that has no relevance to the search.

this is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/xpvt214o/708808/) that shows how my code is working now.

What I want my search to do is for example if I search for Company 2 I want every piece of info related to that company to show up.

hope someone can help me with this.

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchFilterDiv *").filter(function() {
   $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
 });
});
```

here is the html. In real life there are about 50 of those divs, all with the same class of `CompanyDirectoryItem` but it's `data-name` is generated from the database.

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="text"></input>

 <div id="searchFilterDiv">

   <div class="CompanyDirectoryItem" data-name="some-data">  
    <h3> Some Company</h3>
      <a>some-data</a>
      <p> some text</p> 
   </div> 


   <div class="CompanyDirectoryItem" data-name="other-data">  
    <h3> Company 2 </h3>
     <a>other-data</a>
     <p>part of stuff</p> 
   </div> 

   <div class="CompanyDirectoryItem" data-name="data-of-data">  
    <h3> Company 3 </h3>   
     <a>data-of-data</a>
     <p>sportsware company</p> 
     <p>adress</p>  
   </div> 

 </div>
```

Comment: You need to return a boolean from the function you pass to `filter`

Comment: How can I do that? I'm a total noob when it comes to other things than html and css :)

Comment: Change your filter function to `return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1`. Then the result of your filter will be the divs that match the query. 

Finally you can chain operations on that. For example `$('...').filter(...).toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `*`, you just need to put `div.CompanyDirectoryItem` in jquery selector which will return whole div and not just matching element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchFilterDiv div.CompanyDirectoryItem").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/708895/)

Comment: Thank you very much, some times my eyes don't see the obvious :)